# How can I detect a broken video link using player JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, video.js

My site plays some videos, whose sources may change after a few days. When a user watch a video, if it doesn't work (because its source link has just been changed), how can I immediately know that the link has been changed, so that I can update new link for the video?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can know about it when this happens on the user side, is to program some logic to notify you.

For example an ajax call to a PHP script on your server, that in turn sends you an e-mail.

The player will dispatch an `error` event if the source is not available. When the error event is thrown, you do the ajax call and you will receive a mail.

From [the docs](https://github.com/embedly/player.js#playerjs):

```
player.on('error', function(){
  console.log('an error has occurred');
  // do an ajax call to a PHP script that sends an e-mail
}, this);
```

If you can I suggest doing the checking of availability of all the videos at once on the server with a PHP script that runs every day or so.

Comment: I mean, how can I use that event? it seems like there is no document about that

Comment: I updated my answer, if you show your player code I can be more specific about where to place it.